# How can I keep my dog from chewing on and destroying things?

Tags: dogs, behavior

My dog is almost 7 months old now, and she destroys everything. The second I look away she rips something apart. She eats the carpet, clothes, her toys, pumpkins, shoes, any kind of cord, boxes, her metal cage, even the wall. I can't get her to stop - the second I look away she'll be gnawing on something. I don't want to just always have a muzzle on her.

Is there anything I can do to keep her from chewing on things and destroying them?